# How can I migrate my old js code to react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello everybody i'm working on reactjs i'm about migrating my js code to reactjs  here i have an issue if you want to help me thanks for advance 
   i puted this code edited by a good man

```
       {props
        .data
        .releases
        .map((release, i) => <Fragment key={i}>
          <tr>
            <td colspan={acts.length}>{release.id}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            {Object
              .keys(release.storiesByTasks)
              .map((storyByTasksKeys, i) => <td key={i}>
                <ul>
                  {release
                    .storiesByTasks[storyByTasksKeys]
                    .map((taskss, j) => <li key={j}>{taskss.id}</li>)
}
                </ul>
              </td>)
}
          </tr>
        </Fragment>)
}
```

this is the data

```
this.state = {
      data: {
    activities: [
      {
        id: 'A1',
        tasks: [
          {
            id: 'A1.T1'
          },
          {
            id: 'A1.T2'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'A2',
        tasks: [
          {
            id: 'A2.T1'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'A3',
        tasks: []
      }
    ],
    releases: [
      {
        id: 'R1',
        storiesByTasks: {
          'A1.T1': [
            {
              id: 'A1.T1.S1'
            },
            {
              id: 'A1.T1.S2'
            }
          ],
          'A1.T2': [
            {
              id: 'A1.T2.S1'
            },
            {
              id: 'A1.T2.S2'
            },
            {
              id: 'A1.T2.S3'
            }
          ],
        }
      },
      {
        id: 'R2',
        storiesByTasks: {
          'A1.T2': [
            {
              id: 'A1.T2.S4'
            },
            {
              id: 'A1.T2.S5'
            }
          ],
          'A2.T1': [
            {
              id: 'A2.T1.S1'
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  };
```

in the old js code i created a table named taskss yellow one  var taskss = []; where i pushed all the tasks from the data and i pushed emty object into it so i can display things like this [image]

i want the same in react it gives me this [image]

Comment: click on and display this and see the big diffrence

Comment: Holy for loop Batman

Comment: how can i change them? dont know howa nested loop works in react

Answer (score 3):

According to your data, this is how achieved that:

```
return (
  <table border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>{acts.map((cell, i) => <td key={i}>{cell != null ? cell.id : " "}</td>)}</tr>
      <tr>{taskss.map((cell, i) => <td key={i}>{cell != null ? cell.id : " "}</td>)}</tr>
      {
         props
         .data
         .releases
         .map((release, i) =>
           <React.Fragment key={i}>
             <tr><td colspan={acts.length}>{release.id}</td></tr>
             <tr>
             {
               taskss.map((tasks, j) =>
                 <td key={j}>
                 { 
                   tasks.id && release.storiesByTasks[tasks.id] ?
                   <ul>
                   {release.storiesByTasks[tasks.id].map((story, k) =><li key={k}>{story.id}</li>)}
                   </ul> : null
                  }
                  </td>
                )
              }
            </tr>
          </React.Fragment>
        )
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/h3vj6gtu/2/#&togetherjs=lcOrSkFlET

Comment: I'm not sure about the structure, but I definitively think this is the best example, by using the map function. Most readable aswell.

Comment: @VlatkoVlahek thank you very much for your answer i inserted your code and it tells me that release is not afunction

Comment: If the data is part of your state, it should be `this.state.data.releases.map(...)`. And apparently, `storiesByTask` is an object, not an array, so you can't `map` it.

Comment: @Striped this is not the problem i did pass the state < StoryMap data={this.state.data}/> with this line

Comment: it works very well thank you very much can we be friends ? :p @Striped

Comment: @Striped gimme ur facebook :D

Comment: @Striped god bless you thank you again i will add you on twitter

Comment: @Striped look brother what i posted if you have time

Comment: We need to mix taskss and releases data. Could you make a jsfiddle with your actual data that I can use for testing purpose ?

Comment: @Striped no mixing just looping through the taskss array and then display the stroiesbytasks with the taskss id
this is the plnkr link http://plnkr.co/edit/CPuPmtsTkS8wUuUJmn7f?p=preview

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. We need to map the taskss data and use them with the storiesByTasks.

Comment: @Striped yeah did you see the plnkr?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167274/discussion-between-striped-and-ahmed-feki).

Comment: I have updated the answer with the final version and the jsfiddle link.

Comment: hey thank you so much your an angel *.* but where is the link?